# React best way to handle empty object before mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React class, and it wants to render an object shown below:

```
data: {
    title: "haha",
    description: {
        country: "US",
        year: "1996"
    }
}
```

But, when React wants to render it, it gives an error.

**Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: receiveComponent(...): Can only update a mounted component**

I think the problem is in the **getInititalState**, I declare my data as an empty object, so when I get my full data object after the timeout, React will try to map my data object to the component, but it gives error.

But one interesting thing is, I have no problem accesing **this.props.title.title**, but not **this.props.title.description.country**, it will give undefined

But, when I console.log it, I could see my object. But React cant access it!

My guessing is when React initializing from the empty object, it will only init the virtual DOM with the 1st and 2nd level of the data object.

That the reason, when I try to access **this.props.data.data.title** is OK but not **this.props.data.data.description.country**

Below is my code

```
var BookBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { data: {} };
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('timeout');
            that.setState({
                data: {
                    title: "haha",
                    description: {
                        country: "US",
                        year: "1996"
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.data.title}</h1>
                <TestBox title={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var TestBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.props.title);
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{ this.props.title.description.country }</p>
                <p>{ this.props.title.title }</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

May I know what is the best way to handle this problem? should i init my data object structure in the **getInitialState** or there is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting `Can only update a mounted component` error because you are using `componentWillMount` and `settimeout` together, but you dont know if the component has been mounted by the time `settimeout` function fires.

Since you know what your state is beforehand, I think it is best to return your data from `getInitialState` function.

You can also use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` function. That way you can be sure the component is mounted when `componentDidMount` is called.

Any time time you are using asycn functions like `settimeout` or a xhr call, you should use `this.isMounted()` in the callback function, to check that the component is still mounted by the time the callback fires.

For example, if you didnt know the state beforehand, you could fire an xhr call in the `componentDidMount` function, check `this.isMounted()` in the success callback and `setState`.

As for the error on `<p>{ this.props.title.description.country }</p>` line: At initial render `this.state.data` (BookBox) is an empty object so is `this.props.title`(TestBox). Accessing empty object's (`{ }`) `title` property is `undefined`. No problem there. Accessing `description` is also `undefined`. But accessing `undefined`'s `country` is error. To avoid this error you can create a `description` variable: `description = this.props.title.description || {}` and use `<p>{description.country}</p>` to make sure your code doesnt break if `this.props.title` is empty.

Comment: if you copy my working example, and you remove the    <p>{ this.props.title.title }</p>, you have no problem rendering it, but if you add  <p>{ this.props.title.description.country }</p>, that thing breaks, and I dont know why...

Comment: At initial render `this.state.data` (BookBox) is an empty object so is `this.props.title`(TestBox). accessing empty object's (`{ }`)  `title` property is `undefined`. no problem there. accessing `description` is also `undefined`. but accessing `undefined`'s `country` is error.

Comment: bingo! i got it!! so the only way to solve this problem is to init the object array first right? there is no other way?

Comment: Since you know the initial state beforehand, you should use `getInitialState` function. If you didnt know the state, you could fire an xhr call in the `componentDidMount` function, check `this.isMounted()` in the success callback and `setState`.

Comment: Also in `TestBox` component I would do `description = this.props.title.description || {}` and `<p>{description.country}</p>` to make sure my code doesnt break if `this.props.title` is empty.

Comment: that is a very good way! it would be nice if you could update your answer with the answer from comment! TY :)

Comment: @nilgun what if this.isMounted() === false? Shall I fire XHR again?

Comment: @EviSong if the component is unmounted by the time XHR result arrives, I dont see much choice but to do nothing. The component has been removed from DOM already. Firing a new xhr would not re-mount the component. A component can not mount itself. I think you should check why the component is being unmounted by its parents. Maybe move the XHR call up to the parent component which unmounts the component and remount/update it when the result arrives.